# "org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheServerNotFoundException Error" when trying to fetch value from Ignite cache

Tags: java, caching, ignite

Using Spring Boot integrated with Apache Ignite, I'm trying to cluster four servers (IPs).

I have not given the configuration `<property name="clientMode" value="true"/>`, which means all the four IPs are acting as servers.

```
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=ca01c73e, uptime=17:40:06.266]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=2, CPUs=12]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.03%, avg=0.02%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=25]
    ^-- Heap [used=66MB, free=70.66%, comm=217MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=91MB, free=-1%, comm=93MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
```

What does the "Host" and "nodes" denote here? Even though my cache is up and running, I get an error

> "org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheServerNotFoundException","message":"Failed to map keys for cache (all partition nodes left the grid) [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], cache=hcache]"

My configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg"
        class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="hcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="HOURS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="1" />

                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="HOURS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="24" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="wcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="DAYS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="7" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events -->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />

                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />

                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />

                <!--Cache events -->
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
                <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>IP1:1093</value>
                                <value>IP2:1093</value>
                                <value>IP3:1093</value>
                                <value>IP4:1093</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is how I start my Ignite cache via code:

```java
@Component
public class IgniteCacheManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteCacheManager.class);

    private  Ignite ignite;
    public Ignite getIgnite() {
        return ignite;
    }
    @Autowired
    private IgniteCacheManager(AppSpecificIgniteProperties igniteProperties) {
        try {

            // Ignite cache will start
            /*Iginite cache is started with the help of the environment specific configuration file
             * 
             * */
            ignite=Ignition.start(igniteProperties.getConfigFile());        
            ignite.cluster().active(true);
            LOGGER.info("IGNITE CACHE STARTED");
        } catch (IgniteException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }   
    }
    public IgniteCache<String, Integer> getOrCreateCache(String name){

        return  ignite.getOrCreateCache(name);

    }
}
```

Ignite cache is started using the configuration file.

`ignite.cluster().active(true);` is used to create the cluster and activate.

Do I have to include further configuration in code or configuration?

While starting my application as jar in Unix, the application and Ignite cache are up and running, but when I try to hit the endpoint which will fetch the value for the key from the cache, I get the error

> all the nodes left partitions

**Note:** I'm not using the `control.sh`/`ignite.sh` files to start/stop.

Below are a few other questions to understand more about Ignite cache:

1. Do I have to follow a certain order when starting my application so that the cluster will happen accordingly? I tried some patterns, but couldn't resolve the error.
2. Should I use this one server acting as a client, and other servers should act as servers?
3. How can I list the servers under my cluster?
4. Using cache metrics, how can I identify the clustering information?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have to say that the question is very hard to follow - I'd suggest you edit it paying more attention to formatting and grammar.

Comment: Which Ignite version do you use? Can you elaborate on what specifically you were doing (started nodes, uploaded data, stopped nodes, etc)? I assume you were starting and stopping the nodes multiple times - if so, it's necessary to know the exact steps.

Comment: I have cleaned up the question a bit, but you should [edit] it further and probably best reduce it to a single question, instead of a collection of questions.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks When i tried to cluster all the 4 servers I i got the error mentioned in title. So i had these questions

Answer (score 0):

Comment are limited to 85 chars, so I just left it there...

- How many nodes to you have? Are you sure you activated cluster when all of nodes had been joined and you see correct numbers in "toplogy snapshot" message in logs?
- What baseline does ./control.sh shows after first activation?
- It is possible you activate cluster and make first request before all nodes of baseline has joined to grid. So, at that time you may request data to partition that resides on node that is about to start.
- Also, it is possible, you face a bug that leads data loss, when you start one node from baseline and second is not belongs to any baseline topology. 
  Please, check if all your nodes are in baseline before restart, there are no nodes without baseline is started when baseline nodes starting. And  check if ignite does not delete partition files from not work directory after restart.

Answering your questions:

1. Try to start baseline nodes at first, then others. Normally, there is no need to restart client nodes (if you have ones) when grid restarts.
2. Client nodes is not designed to store any data. They are useful if you want to have you app and ignite grid on different servers. And allow you to restart app without temporary data node outage.
3. You can see number of nodes in "topology snapshot" and NODE_JOIN\NODE_LEFT\NODE_FAILED events in logs. ./control.sh can show you baseline nodes and its states. Ignite.cluster() component allow you to get nodes info programmatically. Also, JMX beans are very useful.
4. CacheMetrics is metrics for cache, they don't have cluster information. Try yo use JMX for that.

Comment: I have 4 nodes.if could see in my topology snaphot entries are same in all 4 servers only the CPU values changes in each node.
Is it mean that all r under the cluster?
I m not using control.sh script only via code i activating my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is very unclear and you haven't provided any additional details, I have a guess on what's going on, but it's more of a speculation.

The `H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=2, CPUs=12]` in the metrics meeans that you have 2 running nodes on the same machine. These are all the nodes in the cluster. You don't have 4 nodes connected.

The discovery configuration looks incorrect to me.
You're specifying an non-default port `1093` in the address list, but don't redefine your local port - by default it is `47500`. It seems that you need to set the `localPort` property ([`TcpDiscoverySpi::setLocalPort`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setLocalPort-int-)) to `1093` for the nodes to discover each other.

Two nodes are still able to connect - probably because of the multicast. I assume that you have two nodes started in the same multicast group (sub-network). I advise that you change `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` to `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` to make sure the nodes are using the addresses and ports provided in the config.